# pyo3 performances when a lambda function is passed as an argument

Tags: python, rust, lambda, pyo3

I am starting to look into pyo3, and as a test I am trying to wrap a rust library using pyo3; however, I've been incurring in some performances issues when lambda functions are passed as argument.

Assume I have a rust library with a function that takes a callback as an argument. This function evaluates the callback a number of times and then returns a result, e.g.:

```rust
pub fn test_function<F: Fn(f64) -> f64>(cb: F) -> f64 {
    //Not actually an implementation this trivial, it is just to execute the callback a number of times
    (0..225_000).map(|i| cb(i as f64)).sum::<f64>()
}
```

I try to measure how long this function takes by executing this function 1000 times by passing a callback and taking the average time.

```rust
use std::time::SystemTime;
use pyo3test::test_function;

pub fn main() {
    let mut sum = 0.0f64;
    let reps = 1_000;
    let start = SystemTime::now();
    for _ in 0..reps {
        sum += test_function(|x| x);
    }
    let end = start.elapsed().unwrap();
    println!("Result: {sum}");
    println!("Duration: {:?}", end.checked_div(reps).unwrap());
}
```

On my machine, when run in release, this takes roughly 250 microseconds per execution of `test_function`.

I then tried to wrap this function using pyo3 in the following way

```rust
use pyo3::{PyAny, pyfunction, pymodule, PyResult, Python, wrap_pyfunction};
use pyo3::prelude::PyModule;
use crate::test_function;

#[pymodule]
fn pyo3test(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(py_test_function, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}

#[pyfunction]
pub fn py_test_function(function: &PyAny) -> f64 {
    assert!(function.is_callable());
    let cb = move |x| function.call1((x, )).unwrap().extract::<f64>().unwrap();
    test_function(cb)
}
```

I compile everything (in release), I import the module in python, and then I measure again how much time it takes, by executing this function 1000 times and taking the average time

```py
import pyo3test
from time import time

reps = 1000
cb = lambda x: x
summation = 0
start = time()
for _ in range(reps):
    summation += pyo3test.py_test_function(cb)
end = time()

duration = end-start
avg = duration/reps
print(avg)
```

In this case, the average execution time is roughly 20 milliseconds, almost 2 orders of magnitude more than the pure rust case. I didn't expect to have the same execution time due to the GIL, but I would have guessed something closer to the millisecond.

Is this actually expected or am I missing something? Is it possible to improve on this, possibly without changing the pure-rust implementation?

I tried to look at the documentation, and while [it suggests](https://pyo3.rs/v0.20.3/performance) that `extract` is slow, I don't think I can do anything different here, since `downcast` cannot be used here.
Is there anything else that can be done?

---

**UPDATE**

Trying to follow @[Ahmed AEK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15649230/ahmed-aek)'s advice, I wrote another rust function:

```rust
pub fn test_function_alt(values: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    values.iter().sum::<f64>()
}
```

I wrapped it using pyo3

```rust
#[pyfunction]
pub fn py_test_function_alt(values: Vec<f64>) -> f64 {
    test_function_alt(&values)
}
```

I then wrote the following python function

```py
import numpy as np

def foobar(cb):
    vals = cb(np.arange(225000))
    return pyo3test.py_test_function_alt(vals)
```

This function still executes in roughly 20ms.

Comment: Extracting the numpy array to `Vec` is very slow (I think it is equivalent to iterating over the array with a Python callback); use [`numpy`](https://docs.rs/numpy) instead.

Comment: Also, don't use `SystemTime` for benchmarking, use `Instant`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to use the `numpy` crate. A first naive attempt reduced the execution time to 380 microseconds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the GIL is not your problem here, the python interpreter is slow, it takes those 20 milliseconds to invoke the callback in pure python, without any ffi.

redesign your API interface to not make `225_000` calls to python, instead take a python [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) or [numpy arrays](https://pyo3.github.io/rust-numpy/numpy/index.html), which are specifically designed for passing data to a native API.

Comment: I tried to follow your advice, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem, since I still have to evaluate the callback on all the 225000 inputs. What I did was to write a different rust function that takes a `Vec<f64>` instead of a callback; wrap it using `pyo3`; then I wrote a python function that takes the callback as input, creates a numpy array containing the 225000 inputs, evaluates the outputs of the callback on the numpy array, finally calls the rust function passing the numpy array with the outputs. I still get the same order of execution time. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: @Quasark it would be hard to debug without seeing the code, and seeing how much work is done in python vs rust, you could still be doing something slow like iterating over the array in python, or doing extra unneeded work

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. I updated my original post with what I tried following your advice. Did I misunderstand what you meant? Do you think that there might be something else I could attempt?

Comment: After a few attempts I managed to use the `numpy` crate, and actually I reduced drastically the execution time (380 microseconds). Thanks!